# How to display key, value for each object (Handlebars.js)?

Tags: backbone.js, handlebars.js

I have incoming JSON:

```
[{"key":"browser","value":"Chrome"}, {"key":"geo","value":"false"},{"key":"os","value":"MacOS"}]
```

And I have to display this by using Handlebars template.
**I can't use the construction below because **sometimes I have only 2 objects** inside JSON:**

```
Backbone Model
    attr.browser = attr[0];
    attr.geo = attr[1];
    attr.os = attr[2];
```

Handlebars template:

```
<ul>
 {{#if browser}}
   <li>{{browser.key}}</li>
   <li>{{browser.value}}</li>
 {{/if}}

 {{#if geo}}
   <li>{{geo.key}}</li>
   <li>{{geo.value}}</li>
 {{/if}}

 {{#if os}}
   <li>{{os.key}}</li>
   <li>{{os.value}}</li>
 {{/if}}
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer, maybe it will be useful for somebody:
So, if you have a Backbone.Model with list of objects inside, like this:

```
[{"key":"browser","value":"Chrome"}, {"key":"geo","value":"false"},{"key":"os","value":"MacOS"}]
```

You probably can use this template for display contents of each object:

```
<ul>
 {{#each this}}
  <li>{{key}}</li>
  <li>{{value}}</li>
 {{/each}}
</ul>
```